# How to label or mark instances of a pandas dataframe instead of removing them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am doing some operations to remove some elements of a matrix:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: np.abs(x - x.std()) / x.mean() < 5).all(axis=1)]
```

The issue with the above code, is that it's removing the elements that doesn't match with the lambda function. How can I label with them with `True` or `False` instead of removing them from the dataframe?

Comment: Label or mark all elements in each row?

Comment: Yes label them! @Divakar

Comment: Consider adding a sample case.

Comment: @Divakar here is some sample data https://pastebin.com/YdLt42tX

Comment: Meant a minimal sample and expected output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### option 1

You can assign True or False based on the condition to all cells in the dataframe:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: np.abs(x - x.std()) / x.mean() < 5).all(axis=1)]= True 
df[~df.apply(lambda x: np.abs(x - x.std()) / x.mean() < 5).all(axis=1)]= False
```

#### option 2:

Or you can add a column `'label'` to flag with True if the row validates the condition or False if it doesn't:

```
df['label'] = np.nan 
df[df.apply(
    lambda x: np.abs(x - x.std()) / x.mean() < 5
  ).all(axis=1)]['label']= True 

df[~df.apply(
     lambda x: np.abs(x - x.std()) / x.mean() < 5
   ).all(axis=1)]['label']= False
```

or

```
df['label'] = True 
df[~df.apply(
     lambda x: np.abs(x - x.std()) / x.mean() < 5
   ).all(axis=1)]['label']= False
```

**Note that:** `~` inverts the boolean values coming from the condition. `~` can be replaced with `-` or `np.invert(...)`

#### option 3:

You can also use `np.where` to create the `label` column as follows:

```
df['label'] = np.where(df.apply(
       lambda x: np.abs(x - x.std()) / x.mean() < 5).all(axis=1), 
       True, False)
```

or with df.assign  and np.where like this:

```
df.assign(label=np.where(df.apply(
       lambda x: np.abs(x - x.std()) / x.mean() < 5).all(axis=1), 
       True, False))
```

Comment: @tumbleweed can you share a sample dataframe ?

Comment: @tumbleweed check option 3 with np.where

Comment: @tumbleweed I guess because of mixed types.. I am not sure

Comment: So, to which corresponds the True and the False values?... I guess I am confused?

Comment: @tumbleweed True is for any row where the condition is True, False is for the others..